Bend unlinked geometry of one object around geometry of some other object
How can I bend the geometry of the planks beneath not doing it manually with the proportional editing? I've tried doing it with duplicating, extruding and seperating the geometry of the roof, it works but I'll be happy to get some suggestions if there's a better way of doing it


You can select a set of edges which represent the curvature of the roof, Shift D to duplicate, P to Separate into a new object, in Obj mode select the new object, Right click > Convert to > Curve, Move down on Z Axis.

Then add a new Geometry Node, drag into the geometry node one beam object from the outliner and create this node setup:

Play with the "Align Euler to Vector" node parameters in order to get the result you need, according to the orientations of your objects.

Thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my issue completely >.< must be bended on both axis or else doesn't correlate as it should https://imgur.com/a/PQXIskf

You can apply the Geometry node modifier, then use a lattice modifier to bend all the beams toward the roof.

Thank you again!! I've used lattice and shrinkwrap and it works
